# expire_fragment caching in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am using fragment caching in my rails 4 application, I am trying to expire a fragment which has not yet cached. and that is why I am getting an error saying  :

```
"undefined method `expire_fragment' for #<ItinerarySweeper:0xb5a3510 @controller=nil>"
```

this is my sweerp.rb file :

```
class ItinerarySweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Itinerary

  def after_update(itinerary)
    expire_cache(itinerary)
  end

  def after_destroy(itinerary)   
    expire_cache(itinerary)
  end

  def expire_cache(itinerary)
    expire_fragment "itinerary_percentage_#{itinerary.id}"
    expire_fragment "city_timeline_#{itinerary.id}"
  end
end
```

this is  my controller

```
 class ItinerariesController < ApplicationController
   cache_sweeper :itinerary_sweeper, :only => [:update, :destroy]
   ......
 end
```

what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: can you should some code which throw this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change this:

```
def expire_cache(itinerary)
  expire_fragment "itinerary_percentage_#{itinerary.id}"
  expire_fragment "city_timeline_#{itinerary.id}"
end
```

into this:

```
 def expire_cache(itinerary)
   ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment("itinerary_percentage_#{itinerary.id}", options = nil)
   ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment("city_timeline_#{itinerary.id}", options = nil)
 end
```